# Why does BM give the message Improper alphabetic constant

Tags: bm

Why do I get the error message

```
! Improper alphabetic constant.
<to be read again> 
                   \reserved@d 
l.30 ...m operatorname{A} = $\bm{\operatorname{A}}
                                              $
```

with this input

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T3,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[noenc]{tipa}
\usepackage{tipx}
\usepackage[geometry,weather,misc,clock]{ifsym}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{amscd}

\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,textcomp}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{calc}
%
\usepackage{bm}
%
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\newcommand \catname [1] {\mathcal{#1}}
%
\begin{document}

Test mathbf A = $\mathbf A$, catname{A} = $\catname{A}$, bm catname{A} = $\bm{\catname{A}}$

Test mathbf A = $\mathbf A$, operatorname{A} = $\operatorname{A}$, bm operatorname{A} = $\bm{\operatorname{A}}$

Test mathbf A = $\mathbf A$, operatorname{A} = $\operatorname{A}$, bm operatorname{A} = $\bm{\operatorname{A}}$
\end{document}
```

What I'm trying to do is to get bold upright.

Shmuel (Seymour J.) Metz

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you want a bold operator name (upright), just do `\operatorname{\mathbf{A}}`

Comment: @egreg true but bm could probably be friendlier here....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do `\bm{{\operatorname{A}}`, but this wouldn't give you the correct spacing as an operator:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

$x\bm{{\operatorname{A}}}y$

$x\mathop{\bm{{\operatorname{A}}}}y$

$x\operatorname{\mathbf{A}}y$

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm certain you agree that the last version is the simplest.

If it's not an operator you need, but simply a boldface upright letter, just use `\mathbf{A}`.

Comment: I did do \bm{{\operatorname{A}}, ; that's what gave me the error message. I'll go with the suggestion to use \mathbf{A}. Thanks.

Comment: @shmuel you shouldn't have an error message with `\bm{{` with two braces.

Comment: @shmuel You are probably misunderstanding the role of `\operatorname`; it is *not* for printing upright letters in math, but for printing operators such as “sin”, “log” and similar. For getting an upright letter use `\mathrm{A}` or, if you want it bold, `\mathbf{A}`.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to use bold upright for sequences of functions, which should not have special spacing. I'm now using /mathbf for the purpose.

Answer (score 2):

As always with `bm` if it gets confused, and extra `{}` group can help, here with a more minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

%$\bm{\operatorname{A}}$
$\bm{{\operatorname{A}}}$

\end{document}
```

But probably bm should make `\operatorname` safe automatically.

---

A possible extension to bm to deal with this case, and insert the correct `\mathop` spacing is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{bm}

\makeatletter
\let\bm@end\relax
\begingroup
\catcode`\'=\active
\@firstofone{\endgroup
\def\bm@general#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \begingroup
    \let\bm\@firstofone
    \let\hm\@firstofone
    \global\let\bm@command\@empty
    \let\@let@token\@empty
    \let\protect\@empty
    \let\@typeset@protect\@empty
    \def\bm@mathchoice{\bm@m@thchoice#1}%
    \def\bm@group{\bm@gr@up#1}%
    \let\bm@table#2%
    \let\left\holdinginserts
    \let\right\left
    \let\mskip\mkern
    \let\hskip\kern
    \let\bm@prime\copy
    \def'{\bm@prime\prime\relax}%
    \long\def\@ifnextchar##1##2##3##4{%
      \if##1##4%
        \expandafter\@firstoftwo
      \else
        \expandafter\@secondoftwo
      \fi
      {##2##4}{##3{##4}}}%
    \def\@ifstar{\@ifnextchar*}%
    \def\GenericWarning##1##2{%
      \unvcopy{\GenericWarning{##1}{##2}}}%
    \def\GenericError##1##2##3##4{%
      \unvcopy{\GenericError{##1}{##2}{##3}{##4}}}%
    \let\DN@\copy
    \let\FN@\copy
    \let\next@\copy
    \global\let\bm@first\@empty
    \ifx\uproot@\undefined\else
       \def\root##1\of##2{{\root##1\of{##2}}}%
    \fi
    \def\mathaccentV##1{\mathaccent"\accentclass@}%
    \let\@ifnext\@ifnextchar
    \let\measure@lhs\copy
    \let \rel@break\copy
    \let \bin@break\copy
    \let \after@open\copy
    \let \after@close\copy
    \let\ifmmode\iftrue
     \let\install@mathalphabet\def
     \let\getanddefine@fonts\@gobbletwo
     #3%
    \def\select@group##1##2##3##4{{%
      \protect##1{##4}}}%
    \def\use@mathgroup##1##2##3{{%
      \protect\use@mathgroup##1{##2}{##3}}}%
    \bm@expand#5\@empty\bm@end
  \endgroup
  #4}%
}
\outer\def\bm@end{\@@end}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

$a$


$x\bm{\operatorname{A}}y$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't make the construction into an Op atom, thus defeating the use of `\operatorname`.

Comment: @egreg a place holder for fixing bm, look now:-)

Comment: I still find `\operatorname{\mathbf{A}}` much simpler.

Comment: @egreg oh sure I agree here, but `\bm{some long term that happens to have \operatorname` probably shouldn't die with a cryptic alphabetic constant error.